# Add space to previous row

Tags: tables, spacing

I have a table that looks somewhat like this:

```
Group 1        1  2
  Sub point    1  3
  Subpoint     2  3
Group 2        3  4
  Sub point    4  5
  Pie!         3  1
Group 3        4  7
  Cake?        6  8
  Imma bored   4  7
```

The table is generated with an R-script, but the rows are outputted in a iterative fashion. (I tried using xtable, but there is a lot more parsing and string concatenation going on than shown here.)

I want to add a small vertical spacing between the Group-rows and the previous row, so I get the following format:

```
Group 1        1  2
  Sub point    1  3
  Subpoint     2  3

Group 2        3  4
  Sub point    4  5
  Pie!         3  1

Group 3        4  7
  Cake?        6  8
  Imma bored   4  7
```

Usually, adding vertical spacing would be done with `\vspace`, but this adds spacing *after* the row. Due to my script (and me being lazy not wanting to implement a look-ahead), I am looking for a command that increases spacing to the *previous* row. E.g. something like

```
...
&  Subpoint   &  2  & 3 \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\addVspaceAbove{1em} Group 2 } &   3 &  4 \\
&  Sub point  &  4 &  5 \\
...
```

Thanks in advance!

---

### Solution

Thanks to Qrrbrbirlbel, a solution with both before and after:

```
\begin{tabular}[ht]{llcc}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Group} & Value 1 & Value 2 \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Group 1 }    & 1 & 2 \\
& Sub point  & 1 & 3 \\
& Subpoint   & 2 & 3 \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Group 2 }       & 3 & 4 \\
& Sub point  & 4 & 5 \\
& Pie!       & 3 & 1 \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr.7em+0.5em}Group 3 }       & 4 & 7 \\
& Cake?      & 6 & 8 \\
& Imma bored & 4 & 7 \\
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: You could do `\\[1em] \multicolumn{2}{l}Group 2}` without an `\addVspaceAbove` macro. Otherwise `\newcommand*{\addVspaceAbove}[1]{\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr.7em+#1}}` *could* help (untested). Can you add [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: `\\[<length>]` adds the space after the row it ends. But also `\noalign{\vspace{<length>}}` between rows does, although it's not documented.

Comment: What is the difference between `\vspace{<length>}` and `\\[<length>]`??

Comment: Unrelated note: The optional argument to the `tabular` should have one letter, either `t`, `c` or `b`, writing `ht` has no effect. This argument defines the 'anchor' of the `tabular`, if the top, center or bottom should be placed on the baseline of the text. Hence, this is *not* the same as the float specifiers used for a `table` environment (e.g. `\begin{table}[ht]`).

Comment: @MrGumble -- since the solution provided in the amswer meets your requirements, you can accept it by clicking on the check mark below the vote count.  that is the recommended method in this group.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Your point being? I have already done so to Qrrbrbirlbel's comment.

Comment: @MrGumble -- you have upvoted the answer, and that is good, but the answer isn't "accepted".  this question might help explain what i mean: [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)  (i'm willing to believe that my browser isn't showing the latest status, but this isn't so with other questions that have been accepted.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add vertical space between rows with

- the optional argument of `\\` as in `\\[.5em]`,
- a macro `\addVspacebefore{.5em}` defined as

  ```
  \newcommand*{\addVspaceabove}[1]{\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr.7em+#1}\ignorespaces}
  ```

  which builds a strut that extends the usual `\strut`, or
- `\noalign{\vspace{.5em}}` which is very similar to `\\[.5em]`.

In the example below, I also used `\midrule` from the [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package that provides nice horizontal rules.

### Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand*{\addVspaceabove}[1]{\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr.7em+#1}\ignorespaces}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{llcc}
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Group}                         & Value 1 & Value 2 \\ \midrule
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Group 1}                       &    1    &    2    \\
     & Sub point                                      &    1    &    3    \\
     & Subpoint                                       &    2    &    3    \\[.5em]
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Group 2}                       &    3    &    4    \\
     & Sub point                                      &    4    &    5    \\
     & Pie!                                           &    3    &    1    \\
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\addVspaceabove{.5em} Group 3} &    4    &    7    \\
     & Cake?                                          &    6    &    8    \\
     & Imma bored                                     &    4    &    7    \\\noalign{\vspace{.5em}}
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Group 4}                       &    3    &    1    \\
     & \TeX                                           &    4    &    1    \\
     & \LaTeX                                         &    5    &    9
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]